# After restarting query, Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

Tags: mysql

There are a number of questions on this topic, but they all appeal to not knowing the cause.

The cause of my situation is I was running a query that was taking a very long time, so I ran `service mysqld restart` and now, that specific table is giving me this error.

MySQL is running and the other tables load fine.

The error is:

> #2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) The server is not responding (or the
>
> local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Comment: This is not an answer, but for future reference, if you have a long running query, rather use kill or kill query to stop the query (from another connection), that way you will let the server stop the query without hosing your server.

Comment: Kill the process instead?

Comment: Yes, but run kill or kill query over a MySQL client connection, in the current 5.7 docs here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/kill.html

Answer (score 0):

Your table may be corrupted. 
Check how to solve it [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/mysqlcheck/).